# Using Matlab interface to drop Microsoft Access ODBC table

Tags: sql, matlab, ms-access, odbc

I am using Matlab to manipulate a Microsoft Access database using ODBC.  I use the SQL command 'DROP TABLE table_name' and pass it into the exec(...) statement in Matlab.  It drops the table in the corresponding MS Access file, but when I look at the total size of the file, it has not decreased.  Thus, the dropped table is still in the file somewhere.  I want to completely delete the dropped table so space will be freed up.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not automatically free up space for deleted records and tables. To reclaim space in an MS Access database file, you basically have two simple options:

1. Through the GUI, by selecting **Tools** > **Database Utilities** > **Compact and Repair Database/Project**.
2. From the command line, by executing `msaccess.exe /compact database_file.mdb`

I assume that you should be able to call the command-line variant from within MatLab.

Other than these options, you can also script the same behavior. More information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/158937).